# Python Request - SyntaxError

Tags: python, request

[image: Parameter Requests]

Does anyone know why python is treating 'from' as a SyntaxError? The keyword from is part of the parameters. I can request the data from Postman, but its not working on my VScode.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from` is a keyword (`from foo import bar`, e.g.), so you can't use it as an identifier as this call to `dict` attempts. You can still use it as a *key*; you just need a dict display instead.

```
params = {'count': count, 'from': '2022-01-26', ...}
```